# How many rectangles can be found in this?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

[image]

I saw there are 3 in each row, and 3 in each column hence,

$$9 \cdot 9 = 81$$

But the answer is $$441$$ somehow?

how do they get the answer?

Comment: Consider rectangles of all shapes: 1x1, 3x5, 6x1 are a few examples. How many shapes, how many of each.

Comment: This question is not about real analysis nor it's about advanced number theory, so stop adding those tags to the question.

Comment: How is it not real analysis? This is number theory too, perhaps application of modular airthmetic.

Comment: Do you even understand why there are 9 rectangles in the first figure?

Comment: If you read the description of the real-analysis tag it should be painfully obvious that this is not real-analysis.

Comment: @Henrik, I actually dont see 9 rectangles. I see 4

Comment: Then start by understanding why there are 9 rectangles in the first figure.

Comment: @Henrik, there arent 9 there. Only 4.

Comment: @Lebes Let the $4\times 4$ square be $\begin{array}\\1&2\\3&4\end{array}$. Then all the possible rectangles are $1,2,3,4,12,34,13,24,1234$.

Comment: @user314, hold up? How are $12, 34$ there? There are only single digit arrays?

Comment: Hint: Each rectangle can be encoded by one pair of horizontal coordinates and one pair of vertical coordinates. For a $6\times6$ grid there are $7$ possible coordinates in each direction hence there are ${7\choose2}$ pairs in each direction hence there are ${7\choose2}\times{7\choose2}=$ $____$ rectangles. For some $a\times b$ grid there would be ${a+1\choose2}\times{b+1\choose2}$ rectangles.

Answer (score 8):

Since the figure in question contains $7$ vertical lines you can choose the two vertical edges of the rectangle in ${7\choose2}=21$ ways, and independently you can choose the two horizontal edges of the rectangle in $21$ ways.

Comment: where did the $7$ come from?

Comment: @Lebes  There are seven vertical edges and seven horizontal edges.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, where did the 7th edge come from?

Comment: @Christian, but where is the 7th!!???

Comment: @Lebes: Heavens, we all look at the same figure! You have to **count the lines**, not the rows of  little squares.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

A rectangle is defined by choosing a left-upper and a right-lower point. If we choose $(x,y)$ as a left upper point (using a grid notation starting at $(0,0)$ for left upper corner, going $+1$ for every square to the right or any square downwards), then the right lower point has $(u,v)$ to satisfy $u > x$ and $v > y$.

So for the $2\times 2$ we have $(0,0)$ as l-u, then we can have all $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \{1,2\}$ as r-l point, so that gives 4 rectangles, using $(0,1)$ we have all $(x,y)$ with $x \in \{1,2\}, y \in \{2\}$, so 2 options, using $(1,0)$ we can use $(x,y), x > 1, y > 0$, so 2 options again, and with $(1,1)$ we only have $(2,2)$ as r-l point. So 4 + 2 + 2 +1 = 9 in total. Which confirms the statement.

Now for $6 \times 6$ we pick coordinates among $\{0,1,\ldots,6\}$. So 36 with $(0,0)$ as left upper, and generally $(6-j) \times (6-i)$ options when using $(i,j)$ as l-u point, where $i \le 5, j \le 5$, and you have to sum all those... Way more than 81...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $441=21\times21$, and

$$21=1+2+3+4+5+6$$

Comment: But where does the $21$ come from?

Comment: @Lebes, it's the sum of $1$ to $6$.  The question to ask is, why sum those numbers (and then why square the result)?

Comment: Barry, how are there 9 rectangles?

Comment: @Lebes, for the $2\times2$ grid, $1+2=3$, and $3\times3=9$.  The reason you add $1+2$ is that there is $1$ way, horizontally, to position a rectangle of width $2$ and $2$ ways (again, horizontally) to position a rectangle of width $1$.  The reason you square the result is that you get the same sum for vertical positioning also.

Answer (score 0):

Number of squares here, = 6*6 + 5*5 + 4*4 + 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1 = 91 squares.
Now try evaluating number of rectangles by considering cases like 2*1 rectangles, 3*2 rectangles, etc.

Number of rectangles for a grid m*n is m(m+1)(n)(n+1)/4.
Therefore, it turns out to be 441.

Source: http://puzzlesland.com/mathprob/comb-subrect.html